# xml namespace prefix issue at go

Tags: xml, go, xml-namespaces

### marshalling and unmarshalling are not working properly with xml namespace prefix

> go version 1.9.2
>   See below code:

```
package main

import (

    "fmt"
    "encoding/xml")

type DeviceId struct {
    XMLName      xml.Name `xml:"DeviceId"`
    Manufacturer string   `xml:"Manufacturer"`
    OUI          string   `xml:"OUI"`
    ProductClass string   `xml:"ProductClass"`
    SerialNumber string   `xml:"SerialNumber"`
}

type CwmpInform struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"cwmp:Inform"`
    DeviceId     DeviceId      
}


func main() {
    rq := new(CwmpInform)
    data := `<cwmp:Inform>
                <DeviceId>
                <Manufacturer></Manufacturer>
                <OUI>48BF74</OUI>
                <ProductClass>FAP</ProductClass>
                <SerialNumber>1202000042177AP0008</SerialNumber>
                </DeviceId>
              </cwmp:Inform>`

    xml.Unmarshal([]byte (data), rq)
    fmt.Printf("Unmarshelled Content:%v", rq)
    output, err := xml.MarshalIndent(rq,"  ", "  ")
    if err != nil{
    fmt.Printf("error : %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Marshelled Content: %s\n", string(output))
}
```

Output of above program with proper marshalled Content and empty Marshelled content  :

```
Unmarshelled Content:&{{ } {{ }    }}
 Marshelled Content: 
  <cwmp:Inform>
    <DeviceId>
      <Manufacturer></Manufacturer>
      <OUI></OUI>
      <ProductClass></ProductClass>
      <SerialNumber></SerialNumber>
    </DeviceId>
  </cwmp:Inform>
```

but when i change the struct's xml tag from `xml:"cwmp:Inform"` to `xml:"cwmp Inform"`, then Unmarshelling happens properly, but i get below output for Marshelled content :

```
<Inform xmlns="cwmp">
    <DeviceId>
      <Manufacturer></Manufacturer>
      <OUI>48BF74</OUI>
      <ProductClass>FAP</ProductClass>
      <SerialNumber>1202000042177AP0008</SerialNumber>
    </DeviceId>
  </Inform>
```

Instead of getting `<cwmp:Inform>`, I am getting `<Inform xmlns="cwmp">`

- Is there any work around to correct the **marshelled content** ? Is it a
  **go language** Issue ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Is probably the same issue here

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/9519

To fix that you need to use two structs, one for Unmarshalling and second to Marshalling data

```
type CwmpInformUnmarshal struct {
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"Inform"`
    DeviceId DeviceId
}

type CwmpInformMarshall struct {
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"cwmp:Inform"`
    DeviceId DeviceId
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but when CwmpInformUnmarshal will be a part of a parent struct and used to Unmarshal against below xml content  :          <Body>
    <cwmp:Inform>
        <DeviceId>
                      <Manufacturer></Manufacturer>
                       <OUI>48BF74</OUI>
                      <ProductClass>FAP</ProductClass>
                     <SerialNumber>1202000042177AP0008</SerialNumber>
             </DeviceId>
     </cwmp:Inform>
         <Body> give output as empty structs :(

Comment: Yeah it's seems that there is something wrong with tags, but when you add `Inform` to xml.Name it unmarsall it properly. But still you will need to create another BodyM/BodyU struct for this.

Comment: Thanks a ton :) @ttomalak

Comment: Thanks for the workaround it does seem to work but I also ran into the empty structs problem. Can you please explain what you mean by `create another BodyM/BodyU struct` @ttomalak

Comment: hello @hoos, I'm happy that this answer helped you to resolve issue. It was some time ago, but if I remember correctly by this I mean thatm for parent `struct` to properly handle Unmarshal/Marshal you also need to create seperate `structs`.

Comment: Thanks @ttomalak for the swift response! You are right I needed entirely separate structures for marshalling and unmarshalling.